# Continuous mapping and non-random series

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory

Let us say I have two series, $\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $\{X_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, such that $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = a$ and $X_n \xrightarrow{a.s} c$. Now, I'm interested in the limit value of some $g: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$. Let us say that $g$ is continuous a.e. over $\mathbb{R}^2$, in particular 
$$
g(x,y) = x^y.
$$
As such, can I use the continuous mapping theorem in order to deduce that 
$$
 g(a_n, X_n) \xrightarrow{a.s}a^c 
$$
or I have to be more careful?

Another question that is related to such cases: I've encountered the following form of writing limits of random sequences 
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}X_n =c.
$$
Is it a proper notations? I use to $\lim_{n\to \infty} P( |X_n - c| > \epsilon)=0$ for convergence in probability and $P( \lim_{n\to \infty}X_n =c )=1$ for a.s. convergence. Is the afforemtnioned form is only a shorthand for a.s convergence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a_n\to a$ then $a_n\xrightarrow{a.s.}a$ and together with $X_n\xrightarrow{a.s.}c$ we have $(a_n,X_n)\xrightarrow{a.s.}(a,c)$. So you can use continuous mapping theorem: if function $g(x,y)$ is continuous at the point $(a,c)$ then 
$$g(a_n,X_n)\xrightarrow{a.s.}g(a,c).$$

But I do not see whether it is nesessarily to use this theorem in the case of a.s. convergences. We have by definition that there exists a set $A$ such that $\mathbb P(A)=0$ and for every elementary event $\omega\in\Omega\setminus A$ holds
$$X_n(\omega)\to c.$$
Both sequences $a_n$, $X_n(\omega)$ are simple number sequences and all limit's properties holds for these sequences. In particular, if $g(x,y)$ is continuous at the point $(a,c)$ then 
$$g(a_n,X_n(\omega))\to g(a,c).$$
Finally, for proper function $g$ we have that 
$$
\Omega\setminus A=\{\omega:X_n(\omega)\to c\}\subseteq\{\omega:g(a_n,X_n(\omega))\to g(a,c)\}
$$
and 
$$\mathbb P(g(a_n,X_n)\to g(a,c))\geq \mathbb P(\Omega\setminus A)=1$$
which implies that l.h.s. equals to 1 by sandwich theorem.

The form

> $\lim_{n\to \infty}X_n =c$

is not correct. This form assume that $X_n(\omega)\to c$ for any $\omega\in\Omega$. This means that the sequence converges **surely** or **everywhere** or **pointwise**.

The form

> $\lim_{n\to \infty}X_n =c$ a.s.

is better, but is not completely correct since the above limit for $\omega\in A$ does not have to exist at all.

The absolutely correct form of notation is $X_n\xrightarrow{a.s.}c$.